# Could not evaluate current criteria in Python: "Cannot evaluate Cast". Specify 'fetch' or False for the synchronize_session execution option

Tags: python, date, sqlalchemy, casting, fastapi

```
db.query(data).filter(data.id==o['id']).update({data.count:o['list']})
```

The above query is working and fetching results.

Now i need to update the table based on **today** date and this should be compared with **created_at** column which is present in my **data** table and it has **datetime** value

the below two ways the query is what i am trying but i am getting the following same error for both

```
    1. db.query(data).filter(data.id==o['id']).filter(cast(data.created_at,Date)==today).update({data.count:o['list']})

2. db.query(data).filter(data.id==o['id'],data.created_at.cast(Date)==today).update({data.count:o['list']})
```

---

```
Could not evaluate current criteria in Python: "Cannot evaluate Cast". Specify 'fetch' or False for the synchronize_session execution option
```

How to resolve this?? thanks for the updates.

Answer (score 1):

Due to type casting in your `filter` statement, you need to add the parameter `synchronize_session` with argument `fetch` to the `update` function, as so:

```
db.query(data).filter(data.id==o['id']).filter(cast(data.created_at,Date)==today).update({data.count:o['list']}, synchronize_session='fetch')
```

More information on what synchronize session does can be found in [the official SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.update):

> 'fetch' - Retrieves the primary key identity of affected rows by either performing a SELECT before the UPDATE or DELETE, or by using RETURNING if the database supports it, so that in-memory objects which are affected by the operation can be refreshed with new values (updates) or expunged from the Session (deletes). Note that this synchronization strategy is not available if the given update() or delete() construct specifies columns for UpdateBase.returning() explicitly.

Comment: You may just want to simply convert the type of `today` to whatever the type of the column is, avoiding the need to cast and use `synchronize_session`.